# Classification of an "optimisation" problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Usually optimisation problems consist in maximizing a function given some linear constraints. What if one simply has a system of linear equations with some constraints on the variables that come in the form of linear inequalities. Can this be cast as a linear programming problem? If so, how is it classified/where can I read more about it?

Comment: Checking if the feasible set is nonempty (feasibility problem) is an LP. If you want you can treat it as maximizing the constant function 0 over the constraints.

Comment: Side note: Inequalities are in general easier to handle than equalities.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek so as a matter of fact, there's no special need of solving them? One solves the linear system as usual and then checks if there are solutions that satisfy the inequalities too?

Comment: @Dalamar Just to give you some key words: An inequality becomes an equality by adding a *slack variable* or a *surplus variable*.

Comment: @callculus42 oh ok, so in principle I can turn my system into a bigger linear system containing only equalities and adding just as many non-negative variables as I had inequalities. But then I need to add the constraint on the slack variable (non-negativity), right? So I would still have inequalities

Comment: You can also look for "satisfaction problem", although that's usually looked at in terms of integer problems rather than linear ones.

Comment: When you say "One solves the linear system as usual and then checks if there are solutions that satisfy the inequalities" you implicitly assume that the solution of this system is unique. If that is the case then yes, you just check if the other inequalities are satisfied. But typically the system is underdetermined, so you need to check if there *exists* a point satisfying the other inequalities. This is the feasibility problem. It is essentially equivalent in terms of complexity to a general LP.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek ok, so I get solutions in the form "solution of the non-homogeneous + vector space of solutions of the homogeneous system" and I need to look within that set for points that satisfy the inequalities. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Dalamar Yes, the non-negativity is mandatory if you apply the simplex method, for instance. But then you have an algorithm with clear and unambiguous steps.